# Anyonic and plektonic dark matter?

Tags: quantum-spin, dark-matter, spin-statistics

The most studied types of dark matter particles include supersymmetric particles, spin particles that are either boson or fermions. I wonder if there are research about dark matter being not particles from the main spin j, spin 2j-1 representations, but:

1. Anyonic particles.
2. Plektons.
3. Continuous spin particles.
4. Particles not fitting the spin-statistics theorem (e.g. those particles allowed by quantum groups, q-ons or qp-ons or further deformations of oscillator algebras).
5. Miscellanea.

Comment: Anyons can only exist in two dimensions. Dark matter inhabits 3+1 dimensions. There are good reasons that the only spin statistics that can exist in 3+1 dimensions are the standard ones (although I suppose exceptions might be possible).